# How can I get a CTColor from a Hex color code?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am using Apache POI to modify a pptx. I am trying to change the theme colors of the XSLFTheme class.

I would like to change all the colors that one can change in the PowerPoint GUI as described here ("Create my own color theme"): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-word-or-excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904

The color scheme of the theme I get with the following code:

```
CTOfficeStyleSheet styleSheet = xslfTheme.getXmlObject();
CTBaseStyles themeElements = styleSheet.getThemeElements();
CTColorScheme colorscheme = themeElements.getClrScheme();
```

For changing the colors in the CTColorScheme, I need a CTColor as input. How can I get a CTColor from a Hex color code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to achieve. The `CTColorScheme` defines different `CTColor`s `dk1`, `lt1`, `dk2`, `lt2`,  `accent1` to `accent6`, `hlink` and `folHlink`. So at first you need to decide what color needs to be changed. Most of them are `CTSRgbColor`s. And `CTSRgbColor` has method `setVal​(byte[] val)` where `byte[] val` is a byte array containing three bytes fpr `RGB`.

Comment: @AxelRichter I edited the question to make it more clear. But most of the colors are CTColor s. For example the ```colorscheme.setDk1() ``` method needs a CTColor as a input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CTColorScheme` defines different `CTColors`: `dk1`, `lt1`, `dk2`, `lt2`, `accent1` to `accent6`, `hlink` and `folHlink`. So at first you need to decide what color needs to be set.

I suspect you have a `PowerPoint` presentation using a theme already and wants changing some of the theme colors. If that shall be `RGB` colors then, you need overwriting them using `CTColors` containing  `CTSRgbColors`. And `CTSRgbColor` has a method `setVal​(byte[] val)` where `byte[] val` is a byte array containing three bytes for `RGB`.

If the need is using a hex-string like "FF00FF" to define the color instead of using the byte array directly, then `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` could be used. That provides a method `Hex.decodeHex` which takes a string and decodes it into a byte array. The `commons-codec` library is a `apache poi` prerequisite anyway.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class PowerPointChangeThemeColors {

 enum ThemeColor {
  DK1, //Dark1
  LT1, //Light1
  DK2, //Dark2
  LT2, //Light2
  ACCENT1, //Accent1
  ACCENT2, //Accent2
  ACCENT3, //Accent3
  ACCENT4, //Accent4
  ACCENT5, //Accent5
  ACCENT6, //Accent6
  HLINK, //Hyperlink
  FOLHLINK //FollowedHyperlink
 }

 static void setThemeColor(XSLFTheme theme, ThemeColor color, String rgbS) throws Exception {
  CTOfficeStyleSheet styleSheet = theme.getXmlObject();
  CTBaseStyles themeElements = styleSheet.getThemeElements();
  CTColorScheme colorScheme = themeElements.getClrScheme();
  CTColor ctColor = CTColor.Factory.newInstance();
  CTSRgbColor sRgbColor = ctColor.addNewSrgbClr();
  byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS);
  sRgbColor.setVal(rgbB);
  if (color == ThemeColor.DK1) {
   colorScheme.setDk1(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.LT1) {
   colorScheme.setLt1(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.DK2) {
   colorScheme.setDk2(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.LT2) {
   colorScheme.setLt2(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.ACCENT1) {
   colorScheme.setAccent1(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.ACCENT2) {
   colorScheme.setAccent2(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.ACCENT3) {
   colorScheme.setAccent3(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.ACCENT4) {
   colorScheme.setAccent4(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.ACCENT5) {
   colorScheme.setAccent5(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.ACCENT6) {
   colorScheme.setAccent6(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.HLINK) {
   colorScheme.setHlink(ctColor);
  } else if (color == ThemeColor.FOLHLINK) {
   colorScheme.setFolHlink(ctColor);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("./PPTX.pptx"));

  if (slideShow.getSlideMasters().size() > 0) {
   XSLFSlideMaster master = slideShow.getSlideMasters().get(0);
   XSLFTheme theme = master.getTheme();
   setThemeColor(theme, ThemeColor.DK1, "0000FF");
   setThemeColor(theme, ThemeColor.ACCENT1, "FF0000");
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./PPTXNew.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }
}
```

This gets a `PPTX.pptx`, gets it's theme and changes the theme colors `dk1` (dark1), which is the default dark color used as font color for example, and `accent1`, which is the first accent color, into user defined `RGB` colors.